# Problema con Jquery. *Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Tags: jquery, vb.net, webservice

Estoy obteniendo a través de un servicio web la url en Base64 de una imagen que se obtiene abriendo un openfiledialog.

Esta es la función que consume el servicio:

```
$('#Services').click(function () {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:8023/PruebaServicio/GetString',
        contentType: 'application/json; utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data != undefined) {
                var img = document.getElementById("imgPrueba");
                img.src=data;
            }
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        }

    });
});
```

});

El problema es que sólo me funciona a medias en con IE, con google chrome no me funciona. En la libreria jquery 2.1.1.js aparece el sig. error:

xhr.send( options.hasContent && options.data || null );
*Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Comment: y si intentas url: '/PruebaServicio/GetString'

Answer (score 1):

No veo que estes mandando un JSON al servidor asi que prueba quitando esta línea:

```
 contentType: 'application/json; utf-8',
```

Veo que tu estas esperando un JSON como respuesta del servidor por la línea

```
 dataType: 'json'
```

Si es así y sigue sin funcionar quitando el **contentType** asegurate que en el RESPONSE de tu servicio, ahi si tengas seteado el contentType  con application/json y el charset con utf-8

Comment: Efectivamente, eliminé el contentType y con eso pues abre el openFileDialog, pero a la hora de cargar la imagen no la muestra.

Comment: ¿Sale algún error?
¿Tienes alguna respuesta válida?
¿En ningun explorador funciona?

Comment: Este es el error: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8023/PruebaServicio/GetString. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:49236' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Por lo que entiendo tu servicio esta en  localhost:8023/PruebaServicio/, tu js está ejecutandose desde el mismo host y puerto ?

Comment: Si, en efecto. Funciona en Internet Explorer a medias. Es decir, carga la imagen solo una vez. Si yo quiero volver a seleccionar una nueva, pues no hace nada. Y en google chrome no carga ninguna imagen.

Comment: Intenta agregando esto en el lado del servidor Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");